# Is there a way to create a label so when the compiler runs it replaces that label with the statement in java

Tags: java

Sorry about the poor wording. I have a list of String arrays and each index corresponds to a category. For example list.get(i)[1] will always hold a name. What I want is to enter NAME in my code and when I compile, it automatically replaces NAME with that statement. I'm pretty sure I've seen this before, but I couldn't find anything when I searched for it.

Comment: In C you do this with #define preprocessor statements. I don't know about Java though, but my guess is that it's not possible like that.

Comment: Totally unclear what you are looking for. Post code, that would help.

Comment: Java doesn't have any macro expansion features, but it does have object orientation. Make a class to wrap your ill-defined data structure and give it a `getName()` function.

Comment: Yes, #define was what I was thinking of. I guess Java doesn't have anything like that though. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: If you have named fields, I would use custom class instead of an array.  IMHO, This is the natural way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Java. You are talking about C macros, which don't exist in Java. However, you can create a wrapper object that does something similar. Here's an example:

```
public class MyData {
  private List<String[]> internalData;

  public MyData(List<String[] internalData) {
    this.internalData = internalData;
  }

  public getName(int index) {
    return internalData.get(index)[1];
  }
  public getAddress(int index) {  // For example
    return internalData.get(index)[2];
  }

  // Here, expose any methods of List that you need, such as size()
  // So you can use a for loop correctly
  public int size() {
    return internalData.size();
  }
}
```