# How do we simplify this kind of code in Java? Something like macros in C?

Tags: java, macros

```
public static boolean diagonals(char[][] b, int row, int col, int l) {

            int counter = 1; // because we start from the current position
            char charAtPosition = b[row][col];
            int numRows = b.length;
            int numCols = b[0].length;
            int topleft = 0;
            int topright = 0;
            int bottomleft = 0;
            int bottomright = 0;
            for (int i=row-1,j=col-1;i>=0 && j>=0;i--,j--) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    topleft++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i=row-1,j=col+1;i>=0 && j<=numCols;i--,j++) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    topright++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i=row+1,j=col-1;i<=numRows && j>=0;i++,j--) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    bottomleft++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i=row+1,j=col+1;i<=numRows && j<=numCols;i++,j++) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    bottomright++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return topleft + bottomright + 1 >= l || topright + bottomleft + 1 >= l; //in this case l is 5
    }
```

After I was done posting the code above [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705431/java-2d-array-diagonals-for-game/13706657#13706657), I couldn't help but wanted to simplify the code by merging the four pretty much the same loops into one method.

Here's the kind of method I want to have:

```
public int countSteps(char horizontal, char vertical) {
   
}
```

Two parameters `horizontal` and `vertical` can be either `+` or `-` to indicate the four directions to walk in. What I want to see if possible at all is `i++;` is generalized to `i horizontal horizontal;` when `horizontal` taking the value of `+`.

What I don't want to see is `if` or `switch` statements, for example:

```
public int countSteps(char horizontal, char vertical) {
     if (horizontal == '+' && vertical == '-') {
         for (int i=row-1,j=col+1;i>=0 && j<=numCols;i--,j++) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    topright++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
     } else if (horizontal == '+' && vertical == '+') {
          for (int i=row+1,j=col+1;i>=0 && j<=numCols;i++,j++) {
                if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
                    topright++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
     } else if () {

     } else {

     }
}
```

Since it is as tedious as the original one. Note also that the comparing signs for the loop condition `i>=0 && j<=numCols;` for example, `>= && <=` have correspondence with the value combination of `horizontal` and `vertical`.

Sorry for my bad wording, please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: I answered this question today too in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705010/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-label-so-when-the-compiler-runs-it-replaces-that-labe/13705412#13705412 The short answer is no, you can't do this

Comment: @durron597 Yeah I read that one as well. Maybe extract macros is not possible, but I do believe there must be some way to simplify the four loops into one. That's why I'm asking for people's wisdom :)

Comment: Did you notice that my code in the other diagonals thread only has one loop? Usually it's just a matter of doing a little math to keep the loops the same. I'll try to show you in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily convert the loops to something like:

```
int doit(int i_incr, int j_incr) {
    int cornerIncrement = 0;
    for (int i=row+i_incr, j=col+j_incr; i>=0 && j>=0; i+=i_incr, j+=j_incr) {
        if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
            cornerIncrement++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return cornerIncrement;
}
```

And then repeat 4 times...

```
int increment = doit(+1, -1);  // Or (-1, +1) etc
topLeft += increment;  // Or bottomLeft/topRight/bottomRight
```

Comment: +1 for the idea; -.25 for the name.  You're lucky i round up.

Comment: +1 I like the idea, but still something is missing from this one: how do you decide `i>=0` or `i<=size`?

Comment: @cHao - I'm  not very creative this early in the morning.

Comment: @TerryLi - Yeah, I missed that point.  You can (somewhat dangerously) compare for inequality only.  Another messier option (that I like even less) is to have two separate vars -- one that always increments (or maybe always counts down) for loop count and the other that increments or decrements with ?_incr for the array index.

Comment: @HotLicks I think I get your idea, which somehow completes the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

So you have these two loops:

```
for (int i=row-1,j=col-1;i>=0 && j>=0;i--,j--) {
  if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
    topleft++;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
for (int i=row-1,j=col+1;i>=0 && j<=numCols;i--,j++) {
  if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
    topright++;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

First, turn your counters into an array, i.e. `topleft` -> `counter[0]` and `topright` -> `counter[1]`

Then, turn the difference between the code into variables, so you have:

```
for(direction = 0; direction < 2; direction++) {
  int offset = direction * 2 - 1; // This is what I mean by doing some math
  for(int i=row-1,j=col+offset;i>=0 && -j*offset>=-numCols*direction;i--,j+=offset) {
  if (b[i][j]==charAtPosition) {
    counter[direction]++;
    // etc.
```

The math can get ugly sometimes, or you can do it in a separate line. Look at [my other post on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705431/java-2d-array-diagonals-for-game/13705936#13705936) for an elegant way to do the math in this particular problem using `? :` syntax.